# how to fix "list indices must be integers, not list"

Tags: python, typeerror

Hi i would like to know what is wrong with this code

```
f = open('test.txt', 'a+')
yourResult = [line.split(',') for line in f.readlines()]
for answer in yourResult:
    print (yourResult[answer])

a = raw_input('What Was That')
Format = (answer + ' : ' + a + ', ')
f.write(Format)
print (Format)
File = open('test.txt', 'r')
```

Comment: `answer` still a list. You should be clear with `yourResult`. If not, you can `print` it.

Comment: In free time look on this - "It is good practice to use the `with` keyword when dealing with file objects. This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way." https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Answer (score 1):

`yourResult[answer]` can't work, the `[]` are expecting integer. when you do:

`for answer in yourResult:`, `answer` is a **list**(thanks bruno desthuilliers).

You should do:

```
for answer in yourResult:
    print (answer)
```

here, answer will be `yourResult[0]`, then `yourResult[1]` etc..

Comment: In this case, `answer` is actually a `list`, cf the `line.split()` call when building `yourResult`.

Answer (score 1):

Python's `for` loop doesn't yield indices but the item in the sequence itself, so here, inside the loop, `answer` is already an element of `yourResult`. IOW, you want:

```
for answer in yourResult:
    print (answer)
```

As a side note:

1/ a `file` object is an iterable, so you don't need to use `readlines()`, you can (and should) directly iterate over the file (it will avoid loading the whole content in memory):

2/ `open()` is context manager which takes care of properly closing the file.

The clean version of your code would then be:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    yourResult = [line.split(',') for line in f]

for answer in yourResult:
    print(answer)
```

Comment: Yeah this one should be the accepted answer, the `with open` is important to note

Answer (score 0):

When you use a for this way, `answer` is one of the elements of yourResult, not the index of such an element.
To do what you want with indexes, do :

```
for answer in range(len(yourResult)):
    print(yourResult[answer])
```

In this case, you'll look inside yourResult by using indexes.

If not, you can do :

```
for answer in yourResult:
    print(answer)
```

In this case, you loop directly at the elements inside the array, thus not needing to access them through indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use

```
print(yourResult[answer])
```

using

```
print(answer)
```

will do what I expect you want.
Since you have created yourResult as a list, yourResult[x] expects x to be a number from 0 to `len(yourResult)-1`.
By doing

```
for answer in yourResult
```

You are iteratively setting answer to each item in yourResult.